# How to send an argument when using Artisan::call?

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to run an `Artisan` command with an argument, but I can't figure out how. How do you do it? If I run `php artisan video:webmtomp4 N` in the terminal, it works fine.

```
Artisan::call(
    'video:webmtomp4',
    [$data['videoId']],
    new StreamOutput(fopen(storage_path() . '/logs/artisan.log', 'w'))
);
```

How do you send an argument to the command when using `Artisan::call`? `$data['videoId']` is set, so that is not a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing my comment to an answer after checking the documentation. :)

The parameters array should be associative, e.g. `['argument' => $data['videoId']],`.